# Como concatenar 2 Strings com Java no HTML

Tags: java, html

Estou utilizando o seguinte input com 2 valores pré-setados.

```
<input type="text" class="read-only" value="${FORM.dataAgendamento + FORM.horaAgendamento}" readonly="readonly" size="40"/>
```

Caso os mesmos sejam inteiros, funciona perfeitamente, porém para strings estou recebendo java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Queria saber como realizar essa concatenação de strings nesse mesmo input.

Comment: Esse valor será analisado pelo Java ou pelo JavaScript? O erro é no Java, mas as tags são JavaScript.

Comment: Você está usando JSP? Quais são os valores dessas variáveis?

Answer (score 2):

No caso você tentou somar dois objetos que não são números. Tente o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" class="read-only" value="${FORM.dataAgendamento} ${FORM.horaAgendamento}" readonly="readonly" size="40"/>
```